# List of specific apps on my iPhone with Siri integration

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, voice

How do I see that list and the commands I can use for each app?

Comment: I don't think one exists. It's up to each app developer to integrate Siri however they want (within Apple's guidelines). The minute a list is developed it can be out of date with an app upgrade.

Comment: @fbara I can't find one either, but I don't know how I'm supposed to be able to get any usefulness from Siri in third-party apps without knowing what functionality exists.

Comment: The app developer will have that info in their Help, web site, or release notes.

Comment: @fbara Thanks for the response. I just have higher expectations of Apple in regard to discoverability.

Comment: Not sure how this is on Apple when each developer can determine how to use the available API. It's like asking to see all apps that display text or play sound and blaming Apple when that list doesn't exist.

Comment: In the review process: Apple: Does app use SiriKit?; Developer: Yes.; A: Which voice keywords activate which actions?; D: x, y, z, etc.

Comment: @fbara  There's a way, but I know neither of us is in control of that. I'm just wanting to know how to use a technology that has been made available to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two options may help, although it's not exactly what you're after.

**One**

When using Siri, at the bottom left of the screen, you'll see a '?'. If you tap on the question mark (?) Siri will list the apps you can use with Siri and tapping on an individual app will list some examples for you.

Another way to access this screen is to just say something like "Hey Siri, what can you do?".

**Two**

Go to Settings > Siri > App Support

This will list 3rd party apps that you can allow to process requests via Siri. For example, if you have LinkedIn installed, it should be listed here.

**Summary**

As far as an exhaustive list of apps and how they can be used with Siri, I do think this is an unrealistic expectation. After all there are over 2 million apps currently in the App Store. How would you make this work in a practical sense? How could it be populated/maintained in a timely and useful manner? I'm **not** saying it'd be impossible, just that it's not really practical and the benefits would not justify the effort involved.

Instead, as developers take advantage of the Siri APIs the onus is really on them to highlight and 'sell' the virtues of their product. I know that's what I'll be doing.

Comment: Thanks for #2: that's the first half of what I was looking for. The second half could be implemented by Apple's parsing the submitted apps' Siri keyword information and associated actions upon app submission, and then included as example pairs on each app's pages in the App Support view you referenced. Or they could require the developers to include this information if they want their app to work with Siri. Then when a new feature is added in an update, the included documentation would just be updated in that view.

Comment: Actually, there is a 'Supports' heading now for app listings on the App Store. This indicates that the app supports Siri, but I don't think the heading appears if the app has no Siri support. You can also search for Siri Apps on the App Store, but as time goes by that'll return a lot of results.